# PHP: Parsing Comma-Separated Values Between Square Brackets into Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, regex, parsing, explode

I have the following string:

```
[aaaa,bbbb,cccc] [aaaa,bbbb,cccc] [aaaa,bbbb,cccc] [aaaa,bbbb,cccc] [aaaa,bbbb,cccc]
```

and would like to parse this string into a multidimensional array that would look like

```
0 > ( 0 > aaaa, 1 > bbbb, 3 > cccc), 1 > ( 0 > aaaa, 1 > bbbb, 3 > cccc), 2 > ( 0 > aaaa, 1 > bbbb, 3 > cccc)
```

How would I do this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What language would you like to do this in? Also the string shown is not valid JSON, did you accidentally leave out the commas and the root element (object or array)? Or does this have nothing to do with JSON at all?

Comment: Sorry. I want to do this in PHP. I know it's not a valid JSON (i tried using json_decode) but unfortunately that's how I have the data.

Comment: So is that a string that you have or a data file of some sort?  If string, are there actual line returns?

Comment: It's a string. And no, there are no line returns at all.

Comment: Also, what have you actually tried?

Comment: All I tried so far is json_decode.

Comment: I have edited your question. Does this more actually reflect the string?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `explode()` and `trim()` functions?

Comment: I know what they do, but couldn't build a function from scratch that would do what I want to achieve.

Comment: And yes, that's how the string looks like.

Comment: I will give you a hint that those are the only two functions you need to solve this problem.  You should try to work with them to get what you need.  You can either update with an answer here if you solve the problem, or come back and adjust your question to include specific implementation problems you are having.