# loop out comma separated array value into multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, explode

My PHP app will upload a selected csv file into memory.  It is then converted into an array using str_getcsv as shown below.

```
//get file from session variable created in upload.php
$uploadedfile = str_getcsv($_SESSION['uploadedfile'], "\n");

//remove first two rows as these contain headers
unset($uploadedfile[0]);
unset($uploadedfile[1]);
```

the array currently looks like this:

```
array(4174) {
  [2]=>
string(180) "productID,ProductBarcode,brand,productType,productName"
  [3]=>
string(178) "productID,ProductBarcode,brand,productType,productName"
```

I need to loop through each row and explode the comma separated value into a multidimensional array. So it looks something like this:

```
array() {
 [row2]=>
   "productID => 001"
   "ProductBarcode=>101010"
   "brand=>apple"
   "productType=>notebook"
   "productName=>Macbook pro"
 [row3]=>
   "productID => 002"
   "ProductBarcode=>20202"
   "brand=>apple"
   "productType=>desktop"
   "productName=>iMac"
 }
```

I believe this question was tring to answer a similar thing but the answer wasn't provided:
[PHP: Parsing Comma-Separated Values Between Square Brackets into Multi-Dimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735147/php-parsing-comma-separated-values-between-square-brackets-into-multi-dimension)

Comment: str_getcsv takes a single line of text and decomposes it into an array. it does not work on an entire file. to take an entire csv file, you'd have to loop on each line and str_getcsv that line individually.

Comment: What Marc said.  Also maybe look at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `file` to read the file lines into an array.  Then get the first row to use as headers with `array_shift`.  After that just loop and read the line into an array with `str_getcsv` and combine with the headers:

```
$uploadedfile = file($_SESSION['uploadedfile'], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$headers = array_shift($uploadedfile);
unset($uploadedfile[0]);

foreach($uploadedfile as $line) {
    $data[] = array_combine($headers, str_getcsv($line));
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa: That was 5 years ago but OK.